# How do I make this code loop?

Tags: jquery, loops, callback, setinterval

I would like to know how to make the below code loop, I know I need some sort of callback/setInterval but how do I implement this? Many thanks!

```
$('.1').fadeIn(2500, function() {
    $('.2').fadeIn(2500, function() {
        $('.3').fadeIn(2500, function() {
            $('.3').fadeOut(2500, function() {
                $('.2').fadeOut(2500, function() {
                    $('.1').fadeOut(2500, function() {
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

P.S. This code runs on document ready

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the OP's comments this should be an infinite loop of fading in an out. Try the following

```
(function () {
  var all = [1, 2, 3];
  var rev = all.reverse();

  var doFadeOut = function (index) {
    $('.' + rev[index]).fadeOut(2500, function () {
      index++;
      if (index < rev.length) {
        doFadeOut(index);
      } else {
        doFadeIn(0);
      }
    });
  };

  var doFadeIn = function (index) {
    $('.' + all[index]).fadeIn(2500, function () {
      index++;
      if (index < all.length) {
        doFadeIn(index);
      } else {
        doFadeOut(0);
      }
    });
  };

  doFadeIn(0);
})();
```

Comment: A much better pattern. Deeply nested animation code is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the great response, although it didn't do what I wanted it to do (animation wasn't seemless, skips a fade in/out at the end I think), I know my nesting was bad practice but it worked for what I wanted it to do and my code will only be used as a one off.

Comment: @Luke: I'm a bit late to the party, and my answer isn't completely serious, but it works and animations are seamless. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just put it all into a function and then have that function call itself:

```
function doFade(){
$('.1').fadeIn(2500, function() {
    $('.2').fadeIn(2500, function() {
        $('.3').fadeIn(2500, function() {
            $('.3').fadeOut(2500, function() {
                $('.2').fadeOut(2500, function() {
                    $('.1').fadeOut(2500, function() {
                         doFade()
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Wouldn't you just do the same thing as when there are 3, except that you'd fade in/out 3 more elements

Comment: It's something I'm having to put together quickly, I'm only at beginner level. I'll try this, thanks.

Comment: @maxedison: I'm saying that this solution doesn't scale at all. If you have 100 elements, you'll have to manually type this all out.

Comment: This worked just fine. I know what you're saying and it isn't very good practice, but it's a lot quicker and what I'm doing only ever requires animation on 3 elements.

Comment: @Blender -- definitely doesn't scale at all. But the OP didn't suggest that he had more than 3 elements, or that it could grow to anything beyond that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Take it out of document.ready. Make it it's own function and call it with setInterval or setTimeout in the document.ready:

```
function myCrazyLoop() {
    $('.1').fadeIn(2500, function() {
        $('.2').fadeIn(2500, function() {
           $('.3').fadeIn(2500, function() {
                $('.3').fadeOut(2500, function() {
                   $('.2').fadeOut(2500, function() {
                       $('.1').fadeOut(2500, function() { });
                   });
                });
           });
        });
    });
}
```

then, in document.ready:

```
setInterval('myCrazyLoop()',x); // where x is your interval in miliseconds
```

or
    setTimeout('myCrazyLoop()',x); // same .... timeout runs once; interval, forever

Answer (score 0):

```
(function () {
  var all = [1, 2, 3];
  var rev = all.reverse();

  var doFadeOut = function (index) {
    $('.' + rev[index]).fadeOut(2500, function () {
      index++;
      if (index < rev.length) {
        doFadeOut(index);
      } else {
        doFadeIn(0);
      }
    });
  };

  var doFadeIn = function (index) {
    $('.' + all[index]).fadeIn(2500, function () {
      index++;
      if (index < all.length) {
        doFadeIn(index);
      } else {
        doFadeOut(0);
      }
    });
  };

  doFadeIn(0);
})();
```

Looks pretty good to me. only i would create the array by using jQuery("classname").
Don't hardcode values unless you're certain you will never need to change them.

Comment: Shouldn't this just be a comment on my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it where you just pass in an array of class names and it will cycle up and down the array:

```
var classNameSequence = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];

function runSequence(sequence) {
    var next = 0;

    function doFadeIn() {
        if (next >= sequence.length) {
            --next;
            doFadeOut();
            return;
        }
        $("." + sequence[next++]).fadeIn(2500, doFadeIn);
    }

    function doFadeOut() {
        if (next < 0) {
            next = 0;
            doFadeIn();
            return;
        }
        $("." + sequence[next--]).fadeOut(2500, doFadeOut);
    }

    doFadeIn();
}

runSequence(classNameSequence);
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/cRZxk/.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, here's a crazy way to do it.

```
var cycle = function(selector, timeout) {
    var i = 0, step = 2,
        faders = $(selector).map(function (i, val) {
            return [
                function() { $(val).fadeIn(timeout) },
                function() { $(val).fadeOut(timeout) }
            ];
        }),
        nextStep = function() {
            if ( (i >= faders.length && step > 0) || (i <= 0 && step < 0) ) {
                step *= -1; i += step/2;
            }
            faders[i](); i += step;
            setTimeout(nextStep, timeout);
        };
    nextStep();
};
```

Call it as:

```
cycle(['.c1', '.c2', '.c3'], 1000);
```

See [a demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/9bAz8/).